# angular does not wait for promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

My problem is that angular doesnt wait for the promises to be resolved.
as you can see in the inspect from the console, it prints that it didnt get the provider and skills object and just below that the promises return.

added below are the most relevant code parts in my opinion. I made the service using angulars library - $q and used the deferred, then and when options - as you can see in the service below.

Provider Service:

```
this.getProviderById = function (providersId) {
        // will hold backend provider of the provider with id = providersId
        var provider = undefined;
        // if provider object is not defined then start the new process to fetch it
        if (!provider) {
            // create deferred object using $q
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // get provider form backend
            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/providers/getbyid/' + providersId)
                .then(function (result) {
                    console.log('provider by id result - ' + JSON.stringify(result.data));
                    // save fetched provider to the local variable
                    provider = result.data;
                    // resolve the deferred
                    deferred.resolve(provider);
                }, function (error) {
                    providers = error;
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });

            // set the provider object to be a promise until result comeback
            provider = deferred.promise;
        }
        return $q.when(provider);
    };
```

Provider Controller Definition:

```
 var vm = this;
    vm.getCurrentUser = getCurrentUser;
    function getCurrentUser(){
        console.log('returning current user from auth service');
        return authService.getCurrentUser();
    }
    vm.getProviderById = getProviderById;
    function getProviderById(providersId){
        providerService.getProviderById(providersId)
            .then(function onSuccess(providerResult){
                console.log('providerResult - ' + JSON.stringify(providerResult));
                $scope.provider =  providerResult;
            }, function onError(error){
                console.log('error getting provider by id - ' + error);
            });
    }

    vm.getProviderSkills = getProviderSkills;
    function getProviderSkills(providersId){
        providerService.getProvidersSkills(providersId).then(function onSuccess(resultSkills){
            console.log('resultSkills - ' + JSON.stringify(resultSkills));
            $scope.skills = resultSkills;
        }, function onError(error){
            console.log('error getting providers - ' + $scope.provider + ' - skills');
        });
    }
```

Provider Controller Usage:

```
  $scope.user = vm.getCurrentUser();
    if ($scope.user !== null && $scope.user !== undefined) {
        console.log('user - ' + JSON.stringify($scope.user));
    } else {
        vm.initUsersProvider();
        console.log('initiated users provider');
    }
    vm.getProviderById($scope.user.provider);
    if ($scope.provider !== null && $scope.provider !== undefined) {
        console.log('provider - ' + JSON.stringify($scope.provider));
    } else {
        console.log('didnt get provider object');
    }
    vm.getProviderSkills($scope.provider);
    if ($scope.skills !== null && $scope.skills !== undefined) {
        console.log('provider - ' + JSON.stringify($scope.skills));
    } else {
        console.log('didnt get skills object');
    }
```

Inspect Console Showing result of the picture above:

```
user - {"_id":"5835b06b975ace23244bf205","email":"iairbluer@gmail.com","password":"","fbuser":"5835b06a975ace23244bf204","provider":"5835b06f975ace23244bf206","admin":false,"__v":0}
ProviderRegisterController.js:14 providersId - 5835b06f975ace23244bf206
providerService.js:74 providersId - 5835b06f975ace23244bf206
ProviderRegisterController.js:110 didnt get provider object
ProviderRegisterController.js:117 didnt get skills object
ProviderRegisterController.js:122 no availability module found
ProviderRegisterController.js:124 no bio module found
providerService.js:83 provider by id result - {"_id":"5835b06f975ace23244bf206","bio":"","__v":2,"references":[],"availability":{"auto":true},"skills":["5835b220975ace23244bf208","5835b2ff975ace23244bf209"]}
ProviderRegisterController.js:17 providerResult - {"_id":"5835b06f975ace23244bf206","bio":"","__v":2,"references":[],"availability":{"auto":true},"skills":["5835b220975ace23244bf208","5835b2ff975ace23244bf209"]}
providerService.js:56 received skills from db - [object Object],[object Object]
ProviderRegisterController.js:27 resultSkills - [{"_id":"5835b220975ace23244bf208","topic":2,"description":"sdfsdf","price":45,"status":"PENDING","__v":0},{"_id":"5835b2ff975ace23244bf209","topic":1,"description":"ddfgdfg","price":45,"status":"PENDING","__v":0}]
```

Thanks, for all the help :)

Comment: that is how promises work: angular won't wait for a promise to resolve, you will have to put code that requires the promise to have been resolved inside a `.then()` callback. Make methods such as `vm.getProviderById()` return the promise they are using and then move the code that accesses `$scope.provider` into `.then()`.

Comment: if you look at the function definition of getProviderById the implementation calls the providerService which makes the http request and returns  `"return $q.when(provider);"` it is handled after the call to the service in a .then on success, and $scope provider is set there to be the response. so i dont understand your answer please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you call the functions `vm.getProviderById` and `vm.getProviderSkills` they call other functions which return a promise, however these functions themselves do not. Therefore they are called and then move on to the next steps.

If these functions do actually rely on each other you will need to chain the promises together or call them from inside the `success` of each of their respective promises.

Comment: it would help if you could write a code snippet explaining it because i define the vm.getProviderById to call the service function that makes the http request and after the call there is a .then on success that handles the response

Answer (score 0):

In Provider Controller Usage:

```
$scope.user = vm.getCurrentUser();
if ($scope.user !== null && $scope.user !== undefined) {
    console.log('user - ' + JSON.stringify($scope.user));
} else {
    vm.initUsersProvider();
    console.log('initiated users provider');
}
vm.getProviderById($scope.user.provider);
if ($scope.provider !== null && $scope.provider !== undefined) {
    console.log('provider - ' + JSON.stringify($scope.provider));
} else {
    console.log('didnt get provider object');
}
vm.getProviderSkills($scope.provider);
if ($scope.skills !== null && $scope.skills !== undefined) {
    console.log('provider - ' + JSON.stringify($scope.skills));
} else {
    console.log('didnt get skills object');
}
```

When the call to `vm.getProviderId()` returns, the only thing you can be certain of is that none of the `.then()` code in `vm.getProviderId()` has yet been called. But then you try to access `$scope.provider` and it will not have been set.

`getProviderId` must return a Promise to indicate when it has completed. You can also resolve the promise with the `provider` if you want (which is probably better than assigning into the scope here).

```
vm.getProviderById = getProviderById;

function getProviderById(providersId){
    return providerService.getProviderById(providersId)
        .then(function onSuccess(providerResult){
            console.log('providerResult - ' + JSON.stringify(providerResult));
            return provider;
        }, function onError(error){
            console.log('error getting provider by id - ' + error);
        });
}
```

And change `getProviderSkills()` in a similar way to also return the final promise.

Now you use it like this:

```
vm.getProviderById($scope.user.provider)
.then(function(provider) {
    $scope.provider = provider; // If you still need to save it in scope.
    if (provider !== null && provider !== undefined) {
        console.log('provider - ' + JSON.stringify(provider));
    } else {
        return $q.reject('didnt get provider object');
    }
    return vm.getProviderSkills(provider);
})
.then(function(skills) {
    if (skills === null || skills === undefined) {
        return $q.reject('didn\'t get skills object');
    }
    $scope.skills = skills;
},
function failureCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Note that by returning $q.reject() you you abort the rest of the sequence and you have a single place at the end to handle/log the error.